# data member of type object[] in WCF contract containing xmlnode[] or IEnumerables of strings depending on client

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, xml-serialization

I'm using Contract First WCF to create an Service that a third party vendor has supplied the wsdl. The data member of typeor IEnumerables of strings depending on client

When I consume the service via SoapUI I can use the code the request.ProblemDataMember of type object[] can be accessed with the following code.

```
foreach (XmlNode[] xmlNodeArray in request.ProblemDataMember)
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeArray)
    {
        this.Problem += "\t" + (xmlNode.InnerText) + "\n";
    }
}
```

When the vendor sends a message (I presume with ASMX webservice) I need to access the data member as a Enumerable strings.

```
foreach (string s in request.ProblemDataMember )
{
    this.Problem += "\t" + s + "\n";
}
```

My logging is using Newtonsoft.Json Serializes and below is how it looks.

SoapUI

[[{"#text":"Oil Leak"}],[{"#text":"Surface Rust"}],[{"#text":"Squeal at High Speeds"}],[{"#text":"Check Battery"}]]

Vendor

["c1. LF seat motor sounds like it continues to run after seat stops moving \r\nc2. front driver side marker does not illuminate when unlocking veh at night","c1. LF seat down adjustment motor has failed (gear failure) \r\nc2. marker bulb needed -- N/C","repl. LF seat adjuster assy.","1.This is a test inspection.","2.This is a test inspection.","3.This is a test inspection.","4.this is a test inspection.","5.This is a test inspection.","6.This is a test inspection.","7.This is a test inspection.","8.This is a test inspection.","9.This is a test inspection.","10.This is a test inspection.","11.This is a test inspection.","12.This is a test inspection.","13.This is a test inspection.","14.This is a test inspection.","15.This is a test inspection."]

1. Is there a problem with my Contract to allow this inconsistency
2. Is there a way to determine what is the type of the object[] so I can get the data I need into a list?

Thank you.